Rotation in Text elements on GeoServer SLD
Unfortunately, the solution provided in this post Rotating text labels in GeoServer based on attribute value  doesn't seem to work for me.
<Rotation>
    <ogc:PropertyName>rotation_column</ogc:PropertyName>
</Rotation>

I  tried above code within my current lines before <se:Fill>
          <se:TextSymbolizer>
            <se:Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>TEKST</ogc:PropertyName>
            </se:Label>
            <se:Font>
              <se:SvgParameter name="font-family">Open Sans</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="font-size">19</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Font>
            <se:LabelPlacement>
              <se:LinePlacement>
                <se:GeneralizeLine>true</se:GeneralizeLine>
              </se:LinePlacement>
            </se:LabelPlacement>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#323232</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
          </se:TextSymbolizer>

But then I get the following error
line 306: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.opengis.net/sld":Rotation}'. One    of '{"http://www.opengis.net/se":Graphic,    "http://www.opengis.net/se":Priority,    "http://www.opengis.net/se":VendorOption}' is expected.
Line 306 coincides with the line: <Rotation>
How can I define the rotation of all text elements based on a column name?

LinePlacement does not have a rotation, rotated labels can only be specified with PointPlacement (see the XML schema).
So your XML would need a LabelPlacement, which contains a PointPlacement, that contains a Rotation.
Also, if you're hand writing the SLD, do yourself a favor and use SLD 1.0, there are a lot more examples and the GeoServer style editor will support you with auto-complete (which is not available for SLD 1.1).
E.g.: https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/points.html#point-with-rotated-label

You are spot on! When I change the LinePlacement to PointPlacement I do not get an error when validating the style in GeoServer. However when I want to preview the WMS on GeoSever, I don't get a preview. This problem I don't have with using LinePlacement. Do you might have an idea how I might be able to circumvent this problem?
By the way, I unfortunately can't upvote your answer, since my reputation point is still only 1.
